# Travis CI build matrix contains spurious entry?

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I've a Travis CI build matrix intended to test recent g++ and clang.  In addition to those two intended entries, I see an entry, AFAIK, not specified in the include matrix.  How can I either suppress or remove this third build configuration?

The `.travis.yml`:

```
language: generic
os: linux
script: ./bootstrap && ./configure && make all && make check && make distcheck
matrix:
  include:
    - env: COMPILER_NAME=gcc CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - autotools-dev
            - g++-5
    - env: COMPILER_NAME=clang CXX=clang++-3.8 CC=clang-3.8
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8
          packages:
            - autotools-dev
            - clang-3.8
```

Snippet of Travis' output taken from the [full details](https://travis-ci.org/RhysU/descendu/builds/158055261):
[image: Travis failure screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, "the os key also multiplies the matrix":

> If your code is used on multiple operating systems it probably should
>   be tested on multiple operating systems. Travis CI can test on Linux
>   and OS X.
>
> To enable testing on multiple operating systems add the os key to your
>   .travis.yml:
>
> > os:
> >
> > - linux
> > - osx
>
> The value of the $TRAVIS_OS_NAME variable is set to linux or osx
>   according to the operating system a particular build is running on, so
>   you can use it to conditionalize your build scripts.
>
> If you are already using a build matrix to test multiple versions, the
>   os key also multiplies the matrix.

Source: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/

**Builds with multiple `os` keys:**

For example, for each separate "os" key, it creates another build. See here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/cplusplus-cmake-template/blob/master/.travis.yml#L3 or https://github.com/jaredsburrows/open-virus/blob/master/.travis.yml#L3.

Since the default "os" is linux, it is implied in your own question that you have 3 separate builds, that are all use "os: linux".

**Matrix builds with different `os` keys:**

For example, each key is now specified in the matrix on separate lines. See here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/cs-interview-questions/blob/master/.travis.yml#L3 and https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gif-example/blob/master/.travis.yml#L8.

In your question, you are not only specifying a "matrix" build but also a plain build with a different os. When specifying "matrix", you are overriding the default "os" build. But you explicitly wrote both "os" and "matrix", implying that you wanted 3 separate builds.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the language and os portions into the matrix include works.  I've still no insight as to why, however.

https://github.com/RhysU/descendu/commit/ab275ea79b4ff315f99604d6d7f26dd2488aa266

Comment: So you answered your own question or is this a comment?

Comment: Answered my own, but would still happily award the bonus for any insight as to why that trivial reformatting accomplished what I want.  That is, what defines the matrix contents?